# Missing view window on Interface builder

Tags: object, interface-builder, window, xib

I have an issue with a certain XIB file. When I open it from the xcode using interface builder I get all the windows besides the screen preview one (view window).

I tried all sorts of solutions proposed here like double clicking the view object, closing and relaunching with no success. I am worried that it is lost. Please help.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer for this with a little help of a friend.

Double click the VIEW item from the XIB window (where you have the FILE'S OWNER and the FIRST RESPONDER).

I know it might be a novice issue but since I lost some time and nerves on this I hope ti might help others.

Comment: That was driving me insane!  +1